# Independence Assumption Simulation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, binomial-distribution, independence, assumptions

I'm simulating what happens when you break the assumption of independence when you sample without replacement. The rule of thumb is that you shouldn't sample more that 10% of the population. Kahn Academy has a nice video and shows the results of a simulation here: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/xfb5d8e68:inference-categorical-proportions/one-sample-z-interval-proportion/v/conditions-for-valid-confidence-intervals

I'm trying to recreate this with the following code:

```py
    for s in [.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1]:
        c=0
        for i in range(1500):
            p = .6
            N = 250
            population = np.random.binomial(1,p, N)
            ix = list(range(N)) 
            test_ix = np.random.choice(ix, int(N*s), replace=False)
            test_x = population[test_ix].sum()   
            stat, pval = proportions_ztest(np.array([test_x]), np.array([int(N*s) ]), value=p)

            if pval > .05:
                c+=1

        print("Prc: %s, Hit Rate: %s " % (s, (c / 1500)))
```

I get the following results (or very similar).

```py
    Prc: 0.1, Hit Rate: 0.934 
    Prc: 0.2, Hit Rate: 0.9393333333333334 
    Prc: 0.3, Hit Rate: 0.9346666666666666 
    Prc: 0.4, Hit Rate: 0.9426666666666667 
    Prc: 0.5, Hit Rate: 0.9446666666666667 
    Prc: 0.6, Hit Rate: 0.9426666666666667 
    Prc: 0.7, Hit Rate: 0.9473333333333334 
    Prc: 0.8, Hit Rate: 0.95 
    Prc: 0.9, Hit Rate: 0.946 
    Prc: 1, Hit Rate: 0.9586666666666667
```

Basically, as I sample more than 10% of the population it does nothing to the "hit rate" i.e. probability of 95% CI containing the true mean.

I've tried playing with N and p, but nothing seems to effect it. Furthermore, when I remove the "replace=False" code the hit rate get considerable worse!

I thought I had a pretty good understanding of the assumption of independence / 10% rule, but am struggle why I can't break the test!

Answer (score 2):

This is not the place to debug computer code. And I have found
it best to let Khan Academy posts speak for themselves.

However, it seems you want to show the difference between
a binomial model with independent Bernoulli trials and a
hypergeometric model in which 'draws' are not independent.
Notably, this difference shows in the variances of the two
models. So you will get a very different answer from
`var(rbinom(10^6, 95, .5))` for a million realizations of
$\mathsf{Binom}(95, .5)$ drawing with replacement and
its hypergeometric 'equivalent' drawing without replacement.

Of course, a simulation is not really needed here because
there are exact formulas for the variances of the two models.

Comment: I believe the code is correct. It is mainly there to explicitly show what I'm doing. I have a population of 250 Bernoulli trails. I'm sampling various percents of that population and calculating a CI. I then see how often that CI contains the true mean of .6. This should contain the true mean 95% of the time when the assumptions of the test are meant (randomization, independence, normality). However, I'm purposely breaking the independence assumption. This should create biased CI's and decrease the % of time CI contains true mean. However, this isn't happening. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: Feasibility of your last sentence depends on what kind of CI you're using. There should be a valid CI for hypergeometric model also. Granted that CI intended for _binomial_ won't work for heavily sampled _hypergeometric._